# transforming growth vectors

Tags: r, data-transform

I have two vectors. In `v1`  growth begins quickly and then slows down. In `v2` growth begins slowly but then quickly accelerates

```
v1 <- c(1,25,39,49,59,58,66,69,76,78,82,86,87,87,88,86)
v2 <- c(1,2,1,3,2,2,4,3,5,14,29,45,68,90,140,200)
```

I'm trying to make both vectors look more linear

`log` does a decent job on `v2`

```
plot(log(v2))
```

but how should I transform `v1`? `exp` does a terrible job

```
plot(exp(v1))
```

Is there a generic R function I can use for growth rates such as `v1`?

Comment: What’s wrong with logistic?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Please tell us the ultimate goal! Using different transformations will destroy all relations ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, I want to fit a linear model with data that follow the pattern of `v1`

Comment: @IRTFM, do you mean `log(v1)`? That's better than `exp(v1)` but it still makes `v1` less linear than the original data.

Comment: No I mean logistic. It's not the same as log. It is similar to exponential in low values but then tapers off to a maximum. It's "sigmoid".